# PowerShell log output of function

Tags: powershell

I am using dbatools to run some updates. It returns detailed results to the console. I would like to write this to a log file

```
  Import-DbaCsv -Path $_.FullName -SqlInstance $server -Database $DataBase -Table tempdata -schema dev -Delimiter "|"
```

I am using PSFramework /Write-PSFMessage but I am not sure how I can capture the output from this and log it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out

```
$result =Import-DbaCsv -Path $_.FullName -SqlInstance $server -Database $DataBase -Table tempdata -schema dev -Delimiter "|"

Write-PSFMessage -Message $result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code.

```
Import-DbaCsv -Path $_.FullName -SqlInstance $server -Database $DataBase -Table tempdata -schema dev -Delimiter "|" |Out-File .\Logs.txt
```

Comment: so I am using PSFFramework so I would need to save to a variable or use the  Write-PSFMessage -Message  function somehow